# multi thread join the first one arrived and not wait for the second one

Tags: c++, multithreading, http

EDIT:
**I want to fire 2 threads, each will do some work and the one that will return first is the one I need, meaning after I joined the first one, I want to continue and not wait for the next one, what is the best way to achieve that?**
This is what I got so far and it's and my code is waiting for them both to return.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int main()
{

    std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads;

    std::function<void()> func = []() {
        //1.Internal mission
        std::cout << "From Thread ID : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
    };
    
    vecOfThreads.push_back(std::thread(func));
    
    std::thread th1(func);
    std::thread th2(func);

    vecOfThreads.push_back(std::move(th1));
    vecOfThreads.push_back(std::move(th2));

    for (std::thread& th : vecOfThreads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by catch?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili edited the question thanks for pointing out the problematic expression

Comment: You cannot just leave threads on their own, you have to join them at some point. Otherwise the os will just kill all threads when the process exits.